# WPF MVVM binding in ComboBox with two foreign keys both referencing to same table

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So,

i have a table with Persons, with two foreign keys TownBornId and TownResidentialId both referencing to table Towns. I also have a table with Employees with single foreign key TownId referencing to table Towns.

In the usercontrol for Employees, I have a working combobox like in the following example.

```xaml
<ComboBox x:Name="TownsComboBox" Style="{StaticResource ComboBox}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.AllTowns}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Town, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
DisplayMemberPath="TownName" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Town.Id}" 
SelectedValuePath="Id" 
ToolTip="Town"  />
```

Now, in the usercontrol for Person i need two comboboxes and i don't know how to differentiate TownBornId and TownResidentialId bindings. Can you please give me some guidance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `IValueConverter` is one of ways to achieve it.

You didn't show the data classes. Then I assuming its names with a generic example.

1) Create a Converter class in desired Namespace.

```csharp
public class TownsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<Town> result = new List<Town>; // use your type of List or ObservableCollection
        if (value is List<Town> towns)
        {
            foreach (Town town in towns)
            {
                if (...) // your condition here
                {
                    result.Add(town);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;
}
```

2) Then add the converter to `Window.Resources`

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TownsConverter x:Key="TownsConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

3) Then attach it to the `Binding`

```xaml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.AllTowns, Converter={StaticResource TownsConverter}"/>
```